# ora -00907 -missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, ora-00907

I have a requirement to insert certain columns from one table to another in oracle. It would be like below

```
insert into table2 (column1,column2,.....,columnn)     
select  (column1,column2,.....,columnn)     
from table1      
where condition;
```

But I am getting

> 'ORA - 00907 missing right parenthesis error'

in the select statement itself.

I am executing the select statement separately and still getting the

> 'ora -00907 missing right parenthesis'

error.

Any suggestion for correcting the above would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Get rid of those useless parentheses around the columns in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: Thanks for the help.It was a typo I missed by putting parenthesis in select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that placing the entire select clause inside parentheses is valid.  I would have written your query as:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, ..., columnN)
SELECT column1, column2, ..., columnN
FROM table1
WHERE <condition>;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. It helped.

Comment: Yes it worked after I removed the brackets from select statement. A typo I missed earlier.

Answer (score 1):

`ora -00907 -missing right parenthesis` is a syntax error. Somewhere in your code you have a typo or similar problem. Maybe it's a hanging comma, maybe it is a stray keyword, maybe it is an unexpected left bracket or one which doesn't have a matching right bracket .

The thing is, we can't be sure to spot the error from the pseudo-code you've posted. So either you need to publish your whole statement here, or you need to look a your code with a cool eye. To be honest, looking at our own code in a detached fashion is a key skill we need as developers, so it would be a good exercise for you to find the bloomer for yourself.